# How can I make the sudo GUI work without the admin group?

Tags: permissions, sudo, groups

I have a group of users with `sudo` privileges. That group is not called `admin`. The users can use `sudo` on the command line without any problems, however, Unity GUI dialogs requesting root permission don't accept their login / password. They seem to additionally depend on a membership in the `admin` group.

How can I change this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how you are giving them `sudo` privileges. Show us your `/etc/sudoers` file. Is there any reason you don't have them in the `admin` group in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These applications are likely using [Polkit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/polkit.8), *not* `sudo` (or `gksudo` or a similar frontend), for authorization. The default rule on Ubuntu for Polkit uses membership in `sudo` or `admin` groups:

```
$ cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf 
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin
```

Just create a new configuration file in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d`, say `60-local-admin.conf`, containing:

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:<your-group>
```

Comment: Thanks, that indeed did the trick. I was unaware of the two layers.