# Allow regular user to update software via GUI and update notifier

Tags: apt, updates, notification

I want to **demote** a *user with admin right* to a **regular user**.

But I want to let her continue to *do the updates as before via the GUI*. Explicitly, allow the updates to happen when asked to do so via the update notifier dialog.

I don't know if it's possible, and if yes, what sudo rules should I use so that that user can do the updates.

I am only familiar with `apt` command.
What command/software are used to get notification about updates, and then to run the update process ?

Is it too complicated and requires administrative privileges after all ?

Answer (score 11):

The GUI uses Polkit for authentication and authorization. The relevant Polkit actions seem to be, for apt:

```
org.debian.apt.cancel-foreign
org.debian.apt.change-config
org.debian.apt.change-repository
org.debian.apt.clean
org.debian.apt.get-trusted-vendor-keys
org.debian.apt.install-file
org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
org.debian.apt.install-packages-from-new-repo
org.debian.apt.install-packages.high-trust-repo
org.debian.apt.install-purchased-packages
org.debian.apt.set-proxy
org.debian.apt.update-cache
org.debian.apt.upgrade-packages
```

Possibly, you might need the following as well, for snaps:

```
io.snapcraft.login
io.snapcraft.snapd.login
io.snapcraft.snapd.manage
io.snapcraft.snapd.manage-interfaces
```

Additionally, Ubuntu Software does various actions via PackageKit, so actions for those as well:

```
org.freedesktop.packagekit.cancel-foreign
org.freedesktop.packagekit.clear-offline-update
org.freedesktop.packagekit.device-rebind
org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-downgrade
org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-eula-accept
org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-install
org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-install-untrusted
org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-reinstall
org.freedesktop.packagekit.package-remove
org.freedesktop.packagekit.repair-system
org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-network-proxy-configure
org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-configure
org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-trust-signing-key
org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-update
org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update
org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-upgrade
org.freedesktop.packagekit.upgrade-system
```

And for update-manager:

```
com.ubuntu.update-notifier.pkexec.cddistupgrader
com.ubuntu.update-notifier.pkexec.package-system-locked
```

And for synaptic:

```
com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic
```

To configure Polkit privileges, create a `.pkla` file in /`etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d` named, say, `allow-pkg-mgmt.pkla`, containing:

```
[Allow Package Management to user foo]
Identity=unix-user:foo
Action=org.debian.apt.*;io.snapcraft.*;org.freedesktop.packagekit.*;com.ubuntu.update-notifier.*
ResultActive=auth_self
```

See [`man 8 pklocalauthority`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/pklocalauthority.8.html) for more on configuring Polkit privileges, and the output of `pkaction` for more actions. For some reason, I had to use `ResultActive` instead of `ResultAny` before it would ask for the unprivileged user's password.

Comment: seems a very good answer to me. checking right now in a VM if this works. Isn't `ResultAny=auth_self` shouldn't be `auth_admin` isntead ?

Comment: Depends. Do you want actions done by this user to require authentication from an admin user?

Comment: One thing I want to add here: in case you want to use `Identity=unix-group:adm` at your site (or some other group), since Ubuntu 18.04 you need to add this group as well under `AdminIdentities=` in the file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf`.

Comment: @SebastianStark you don't need to add to that file. You can create a second file and set admin identities in it. https://askubuntu.com/a/642756/158442

Comment: @muru even better

Comment: I don't manage to test this.

Comment: @solsTiCe I tested it out on a VM, and it seems there's an additional set of actions `org.freedesktop.packagekit.*` that's needed, and I had to use `ResultActive` instead of `ResultAny`.

Answer (score 0):

The polkit looks a bit complicated to me.

I would add an entry in /etc/sudoers, like:

```
her-login ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: apt update
her-login ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: apt upgrade
# ( check syntax! )
```

And then create a icon that starts  'sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade'

This allows 'her-login' to run just 2 commands as root...
Same could be done done for, say sudo mintupdate, if a more 'GUI' approch is wanted.