# sudoers can not edit network settings

Tags: networking, 18.04, sudo, dns

I have two users which I have defined as sudoers in `/etc/sudoers` which looks like this:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
bob      ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
mary      ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

However after entering their password, none of them can change `Network Settings` to add manual DNS IP addresses. Instead I get this annoying message:

> System policy pervents modification of network settings for all users.

[image]

I have no difficulty switching to root using `sudo su` in the terminal.

So how can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make the sudo GUI work without the admin group?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642753/how-can-i-make-the-sudo-gui-work-without-the-admin-group)

Comment: @muru unfortuanatly it did not help. I have also `AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin` in my `51-ubuntu-admin.conf `. But your tip did not solve my problem when I added `bob` and `mary` below `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`  and rebooted the compute. But still can not change the networks settings.

Comment: The point is that polkit uses the sudo and admin groups. Either add your users to those groups, or add `unix-user:bob` or whatever to polkit. Your sudoers settings don't make any difference to polkit.