# User's sudo password doesn't work in GUI dialogs

Tags: 20.04, permissions, gui, root, administrator

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. I have a user that allows me to do `sudo` operations. I can login with root without any problem.

I'm try to install a new keyboard language through the GUI (Settings etc.). This shows me a dialogue asking for my 'Administrator' password. My user's password doesn't work. What can I do?

Note: recall that I can do any operation form the terminal, as I can log in as root.

PD: I think I remember I need to add my user to a GUI sudoers group, but I'm not sure nor I know which group.

Comment: Is the "user that allows me to do `sudo` operations" a member of the `sudo` *group*, or was it added as an individual entry in the sudoers file?

Comment: I have executed `groups $my_user` and I don't see `sudo`, therefore I imagine is the second option.

Comment: When the GUI displays the dialog that asks for the password, the user is 'Administrator', but I don't find that user in `/etc/passwd`

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by adding my user to the `sudo` group: `sudo usermod -aG sudo $my_user`

The GUI authentication dialog uses PolicyKit, which is configured by default on Ubuntu to use membership of the `sudo` or `admin` Unix groups as a proxy for the LocalAuthority role:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin
```

Users who obtain command-line sudo privileges via other means (i.e. individual entries or custom groups in /etc/sudoers) won't be recognized as having PolicyKit LocalAuthority privileges.

See also [How can I make the sudo GUI work without the admin group?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642753/how-can-i-make-the-sudo-gui-work-without-the-admin-group)